# White box Artifact appearing in render?

Tags: rendering, camera, compositing-nodes, artifacts

I am new to blender, and while I was following this blender tutorial: https://youtu.be/y0DMMwwdBaY

At the 15-minute mark, we start using the compositing tab. For some reason, using this tab causes a white box to appear in my rendered image which does not show in the camera view.
Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Compositing view render:

[image: White Artifact]

Camera view render:

[image: Camera View image]

Comment: could you attach your .blend file or compositing setup

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I found the problem, and since I can't figure out how to delete the post I'll just put this here:
The issue turned out to be a very small object mesh that I had set to invisible that was showing up in a buggy fashion in the render. since I had not done so until the compositing step, I mistook this as the cause. Deleting this hidden mesh fixed it.